# Static Variable in Web Application

Tags: variables, static

It's well known fact that static variable cannot be used in 
Web Application as it remains static through out application.But,is there any scenario where static variable can be used in Web Application to achieve the functionality?

Thanks

Comment: What language or environment you are talking about?

Comment: Irrespective of the language or the environment, i think the static behaves in same way.

Comment: The precise semantics of 'static' change not only between languages, but between web environments in the same language (e.g. multiprocess vs. multithreaded)

Comment: It might be helpful to understand some more about the context. While I think the answers you have been given are correct, we might be able to more readily put it into context for you.

Comment: @ orip Do you mean "static int i=10;" has different behaviors if language differs? or the web environment differs? Or Are you speaking any other way where it will differ?

Comment: How is the Application object in ASP.Net not static?  I'm pretty sure it is a case where a singleton is used in a Web Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but there are cases in which using a static variable in a web application is perfectly fine, if one understands the implications.  For instance, a common usage in .NET web applications using [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.org) and the "session-per-request" model is to keep a static instance of an ISessionFactory around to create new [NHibernate](http://nhibernate.org) sessions.  This is useful since session factories are very heavy objects and generally take a lot of resources to create.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your static information in a number of places...

- In a DB
- In a cookie
- In an Application or Session variable
- In a querystring (or even a form variable)

(Or am I misunderstanding the question?)

Comment: Yeah i understand that static values can be stored in session, View State and the place you mentioned. But Is there any specific funcationality that can be achieved using the Static Variable (I mean i variable declared as Static) instead of storing it other places

Answer (score 1):

configuration data, database connection strings, constant data for the application retrieved from a database source.

Anything that doesn't need to change after it's been initialized.

For example, I could get a configuration setting on a page and use if over and over again. In this example once myUrl is initialized it will never have to hit the web.config file again until the web application is restarted.

```
static public string myUrl = string.Empty

public void SomeRoutine()
{
    if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( myUrl ) )
        myUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "myUrl" ].ToString();

    ...

    Response.Redirect( myUrl );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what web framework you are using, but if you are using ASP.Net, you can assign objects to the Application object or the Session object, which will hold information across the application between requests, and across all requests from an individual user respectively.

If you are asking in a general way, and I suspect you are as this is marked subjective+discussion, then you can try using a cookie to hold the variable across all requests for a user.

As for holding some value for all users, you should have a look at the web framework you are using. You have options such as storing something in a file that is accessible at each request, through to storing something in the equivalent of the Application object of ASP.Net.

I'm sorry if I'm being too pragmatic here, but it's late where I live :).